Athena query find till next value
I have below records

The logic is index will be same till next price found, and count is just row number
I am trying to write the query, but unable to even start like how should I proceed, I was looking if loop is there but could not found.
If anyone could guide, that would be great help

This is basically a variation of gaps-and-islands problem.
You can use conditional sum to determine the index (group) and then use row_number to determine the count:
-- sample data
with dataset (date, price) as (
    values (1, 1300),
        (2, 0),
        (3, 0),
        (4, 869),
        (5, 0),
        (6, 0),
        (7, 259)
)

-- query
select *,
       row_number() over (partition by index order by date) as count
from (select date,
        price,
        sum(if(price > 0, 1)) over (order by date) index
from dataset) as t
order by index, count;

Output:



date
price
index
count




1
1300
1
1


2
0
1
2


3
0
1
3


4
869
2
1


5
0
2
2


6
0
2
3


7
259
3
1




Thanks, it is giving the desired output, just one question, in my actual data there is a few more columns before date, customer_name,order_number,location, where I can put these columns so that it could group by customer name order number, location

we can have same date for customer_name,order_number and location combination

@Md.ParvezAlam "it starts index from 52 order by date" - order by index and count then, it would be a more correct option here. As for the rest - TBH do not fully follow your question.

sorry my comment got mixed

the only modification I am try to do is rather than checking only broadcast week, it should  check other columns also, like when I am checking with where clause for customer name it is giving correct result because there is no duplicate, but when remove where for all customer it starting with 52 diff is other customer may have same date also

select *,
row_number() over (partition by index order by date) as count
from (select customer_name,order_date,location,date,
price,
sum(if(price > 0, 1)) over (order by date) index
from dataset where customer_name = 'something') as t
order by index, count; it gives correct result

@Md.ParvezAlam you can add extra partitioning to both over clauses, for example by customer.

Yes I tried, but index does not start with 1, its starting with 3 if I don't add date otherwise 2
